# How to schedule an async macro from WORD

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm facing an annoying issue where I simply want to schedule an asynchronous macro from another instance of Word, which happens to be the same .doc file.

Meaning, in the `ThisDocument` namespace I have the following code snippet:

```
Public Sub Document_Open()
    Set Obj = New Word.Application
    Obj.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Module1.Test"
End Sub
```

I've declared a new object of Word due to the following reasons:

1. My macro may block user's I\O
2. The user may close the document before the macro finishes its task

And declared a module named `Module1` with a simple `MsgBox`

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox "hhh"
End Sub
```

Needless to say, nothing happened, and I'm unable to check what `OnTime` function returns.

I've also tried the following combinations:

```
"!Module1.Test"
"c:\\....\\file.doc!Module1.Test"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your newly created Word application, represented by a `Word.Application` object, doesn't have the document open. Thus there's no "Module1" as far as he's aware. The fact that you want to run code from the same document is immaterial. It's a different instance of Word.

Something like this works:

```
'''''''' ThisDocument
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim Obj As Word.Application

    If Application.Visible Then
        res = MsgBox("Hello", vbOKCancel, "Hi!")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If res = vbOK Then
        Set Obj = New Word.Application
        Obj.Documents.Open "C:\Users\conio\Desktop\Hello.docm", , True
        Obj.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Module1.Foo"
    End If
End Sub

'''''''' Module1
Public Sub Foo()
    If Not Application.Visible Then
        MsgBox "Foo"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Maybe you'd want to use a different check to differentiate between the interactive run and the unattended run.